# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error on order placement in hybris

Tags: java-8, sap-commerce-cloud

I am using jdk1.8.0_281, hybris 1811 and hsql as DB on windows with 16GB RAM. Storefront is loading fine, but on placing order I am getting Java Heap Space error. I tried to increase memory adding below properties file, but it does not fix it. Below is local properties I added

```
tomcat.generaloptions=-Xmx2048M -Xms500M -Xss256K -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark  -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:"${HYBRIS_LOG_DIR}/tomcat/java_gc.log" -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dorg.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager.mbean=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs=../lib/endorsed -Dcatalina.base=%CATALINA_BASE% -Dcatalina.home=%CATALINA_HOME% -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.util.logging.config.file=jdk_logging.properties -Djava.io.tmpdir="${HYBRIS_TEMP_DIR}" -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000
tomcat.debugjavaoptions=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000,suspend=n -Xmx2048M -Xms500M
```

Below is the stack trace of error I am getting

```
 FATAL [hybrisHTTP27] [ENGINE] DataFileCache.readObject 12319526
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.hsqldb.rowio.RowInputBase.resetRow(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.hsqldb.rowio.RowInputBinary.resetRow(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.hsqldb.persist.DataFileCache.readObject(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.hsqldb.persist.DataFileCache.getFromFile(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.hsqldb.persist.DataFileCache.get(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.hsqldb.persist.RowStoreAVLDisk.get(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.hsqldb.index.NodeAVLDisk.findNode(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.hsqldb.index.NodeAVLDisk.getRight(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.hsqldb.index.NodeAVLDisk.child(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.hsqldb.index.IndexAVL.insert(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.hsqldb.persist.RowStoreAVL.indexRow(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.hsqldb.persist.RowStoreAVLDisk.indexRow(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.hsqldb.TransactionManagerMVCC.addInsertAction(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.hsqldb.Session.addInsertAction(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.hsqldb.Table.insertSingleRow(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDML.insertSingleRow(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.hsqldb.StatementInsert.getResult(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDMQL.execute(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.4.jar:2.3.4]
    at de.hybris.platform.jdbcwrapper.interceptor.PreparedStatementWithJDBCInterceptor.lambda$5(PreparedStatementWithJDBCInterceptor.java:86) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.jdbcwrapper.interceptor.PreparedStatementWithJDBCInterceptor$$Lambda$67/859132519.get(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.jdbcwrapper.interceptor.recover.SQLRecoverableExceptionHandler.passThrough(SQLRecoverableExceptionHandler.java:101) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.jdbcwrapper.interceptor.recover.SQLRecoverableExceptionHandler.get(SQLRecoverableExceptionHandler.java:59) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.jdbcwrapper.interceptor.JDBCInterceptor.get(JDBCInterceptor.java:69) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.jdbcwrapper.interceptor.PreparedStatementWithJDBCInterceptor.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementWithJDBCInterceptor.java:86) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.jdbcwrapper.PreparedStatementImpl.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementImpl.java:313) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.persistence.GenericBMPBean$GenericItemEntityState.createEntity(GenericBMPBean.java:1816) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.persistence.GenericBMPBean.ejbCreate(GenericBMPBean.java:398) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor715.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
FATAL [hybrisHTTP27] [ENGINE] DataFileCache.readObject 12319526
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space ""
```

Comment: Check the fields, no *, no BLOB/CLOB. Either you are inserting exploding data (sub-queries) or copying images or whatever. Without code it is hard to say.

Comment: Does not looks like a code issue, same code is working good in other machines.

Comment: Note that *OutOfMemoryError* is often not related to the stack trace. It's just the straw that broke the camel's back. 2GB of heap might just not be enough. Do other machines you have mentioned use the same settings? You could try the option `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` to find the culprit of the problem.

Comment: Increasing memory does not worked. HSQL database was corrupted, so I did a vanilla setup of hybris, copied folder 'hsqldb' from its data folder and replaced it with 'hsqldb' folder of my existing setup, followed by system initialization.